# Error in declaring an alias with using

Tags: c++11, alias

I wanted to create aliases to make using the `chrono` methods easier.
So I declared those:

```
using Clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<Clock>;
using DurationCast = std::chrono::duration_cast<Clock::duration>;
```

`Clock` and `TimePoint` work as expected but the last `DurationCast` gives me an error:

```
expected a type
expected ';' after alias declaration
```

Now I am not sure what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::chrono::duration_cast` is a function, not a type. You could wrap it in a function or lambda:

```
template <class D> 
static auto DurationCast(D d)
{ return std::chrono::duration_cast<Clock::duration>(d); }
```